# Surprising output of simple Python list program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**I am getting bit confused after seeing the output of following Python program:**

```
t = [0,1,2]


t[2:].append(t[0])


print(t)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[0,1,2]
```

Here, I have taken a list `[0,1,2]`. Why is the output [0,1,2], and not [0,1,0]? Please someone help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: `t[2:]` is a slice, which means it is a copy of part of the list. `t` still holds your original list. Altering the copy doesn't affect the original.

Comment: @khelwood, your comment should be an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `t[2:]` creates another list, and you are appending to that list, but in the end you are printing the original list `t`

To give some light:

`t` is a list object, and when you do `t[2:]`, you are creating a new list object based on the first one. Then, you append to this new object a value and, since you don't store that new object in any variable, the object is lost.

Finally, you are just printing your original, which has not changed, list.

Try this:

```py
new_t = t[2:] # New object with your slice
new_t.append(t[0]) # Appending a value of your old list to this new created list
print(new_t) # Printing the new list
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code, do nothing:

```
t[2:].append(t[0])
```

For **desired result** use:

```
t = [0,1,2]
t2 = t[:2] # we only need 1st and 2nd value from t
t2.append(t[0]) # append 1st value of t in the last of t2 to generate the desired list
print(t2) # print t2 (the desired list)
```

or

```
t = [0,1,2]
t[-1] = t[0] # update the last element of list, same as first element
print(t) # print updated list having desired answer
```